# Problem with http call in angular. Cant send it

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, server, angular-httpclient

Hi guys i have really big problem with angular calls in my app. First of all i will past my code here.

Angular service

```
path = 'http://localhost:3000';
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getProducts(): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.path + '/api/products');
  }
```

Part of server.js

```
client.connect(err => {
  collectionUsers = client.db("users").collection("users");
  hivesDatabase = client.db("hives");
  });
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started at port 3000');
  });
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.route('/api/products').get(async (req, res) => {
  let response = [];
  collectionUsers.find().toArray().then(items => {
    items.forEach(item => {
      response.push(item);
    });
    res.send(response);
  });
});
```

Error: [error img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwfZt.png)

I really dont know what can be wrong with this code.. Pls help me :(

Comment: Please provide more info. Has the server started? How can you run angular and your server on the same port? or how can you connect to a server that has a different port without CORS errors? I assume you are using Express.Js on Node.Js and Angular CLI for frontend is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error was that I used Angular Tour of Heroes applcation as a basis for mine, and I did not remove the dependency

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reason for this issue:

I would go with the below approach:

1. Check if you are getting the correct response by using *Postman* if you have the real backend in place.
2. Always try to return the required object type if its known and required from the service instead of '*any*'.
3. Most possibly due to the having *InMemoryWebApiModule* dependency. This needs to removed, if you are faking the backend in your application.